# Partial derivative of interaction term with endogenous variable

Tags: interaction, instrumental-variables, endogeneity, derivative, 2sls

I am trying to estimate the price elasticity based on a 2sls regression. The price in logarithmic form is treated as an endogenous variable. The price appears in an interaction term with income $\widehat{(Inc \cdot ln(p))}$ and as a polynomial $\widehat{({(ln (p))}^2)}$.

This is the regression:
$ln(q) = \alpha + \beta \widehat{ln(p)} + \gamma Inc + \delta \widehat{(Inc \cdot ln(p))} + \eta \widehat{({(ln (p))}^2)} + controls + \varepsilon$

Now I want to calculate the price elasticity:
$\mu = \frac{\partial ln(q)}{\partial \widehat{ln(p)}}$

My question is: What is the partial derivative of the interaction terms? Which one of these is true?

1. $\mu = \beta + \delta \cdot Inc + 2 \eta \cdot \widehat{ln(p)}$

or

2. $\mu = \beta + \delta \frac{\partial \widehat{(Inc \cdot ln(p))}}{\partial \widehat{ln(p)}} + \eta \frac{\partial \widehat{({(ln (p))}^2)}}{\partial \widehat{ln(p)}} = \beta + \delta \frac{\widehat{(Inc \cdot ln(p))}}{\widehat{ln(p)}} + 2 \eta \frac{\widehat{({(ln (p))}^2)}}{\widehat{ln(p)}}$

I hope my question is clear and someone may come up with an answer. Thanks a lot for any help!